# How do I interpolate an *ngFor variable inside of a string within a ternary expression? (Angular)

Tags: angular, interpolation, ngfor

What I've tried:

```
  <mat-step *ngFor="let name of names" [label]="name" [completed]="name + 'IsCompleted'">
    <button mat-button (click)="redirectToNameUrl(name)" mat-raised-button color="primary">
  {{ (inProgress ? 'In progress...' : "'Sign in with ' + name + 'details!'" )}}
    </button>
  </mat-step>
```

NOTE: Nested handlebars doesn't seem to work either.

Result:

A button that says `'Sign in with ' + name + 'details!'`

I expect it to say:

`Sign in with james details!`

Thanks

Comment: Remove the double quotes around `'Sign in with ' + name + 'details!'`.

Comment: Yep, just got there before me - whoops! Thanks @TimKlein

Comment: Syntax mistakes are off topic here.

Comment: @Reactgular Shall I delete the question?

Comment: That's up to you. You can improve the question so that it is on topic or wait to see if it closed. If you get a lot of downvotes, then I would delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Just try like this

```
  <mat-step *ngFor="let name of names" [label]="name" [completed]="name + 'IsCompleted'">
    <button mat-button (click)="redirectToNameUrl(name)" mat-raised-button color="primary">
  {{ (inProgress ? 'In progress...' : 'Sign in with ' + name + 'details!' )}}
    </button>
  </mat-step>
```

You don't need the extra double quotes around the text